# Is there a way to emulate ReSharper's "extend selection" feature in Vim?

Tags: vim, editor, resharper, text-editor

ReSharper has a nice feature called "extend selection": by pressing `CTRL+W` (I think this is the default) repeatedly, you select more and more from your current caret location. First it's a word, then more and more words, a line, inner then outer block of lines (for example an if-block), then a function, etc...

Basically, by pressing the key combination repeatedly, you can end up selecting the entire file. I'm sure at least some of you will be familiar with it.

I have just started learning all the intricacies of vim and I don't have enough experience to see how something like this could be implemented in Vim (although I assume it's possible). So my question is meant for Vim gurus out there: can this be done and how?

**Update:** a bit of a background story. I've been talking to my ex-boss about all the benefits of Vim, and he thinks it's all great. His only question/problem was: *does it have "extend selection"?* My question so far has been *no*. So, if someone knows the answer, I'll finally win a discussion :P (and maybe create a new Vim convert`:-)`)

Comment: Amazing how nobody answering here recognized the need for a proper (partial) parser. Resharper ovbiously  implements this (great) feature on top of a logical model of the code: the Code DOM. This is also what enables the refactorings to work on the selections made. Without proper parser you'd select 'things' but not proper (sub)expressions. The latter would be useful, but not currently supported in Vim _That is. unless you count Lisp support: `vabababo2k` is perfect for lisp_ :)

Comment: @sehe: You are, of course, completely right. I've been thinking about this problem off and on ever since I asked the question here (seems like a long time ago!) and realized that even if I somehow manage to create this feature, it will only work for a specific language, or a family of languages. Too bad, isn't it? :)

Comment: I've been pondering this myself too. I'd be happy with a 90% solution (I can do refactorings pretty swift in Vim manually for now). However a 'usable' subexpression-matching-selection-expander is really my no.1 dream feature. I'm convinced that is is very possible to come up with a parser that will DoTheRightThing for C#, Java, C++ and C; The only sticky edge cases I expect are C# vs. C++0x lambdas. So I'd probably leave those out for a while (and make sure it's pluggable). I'm still deciding what to use, as I kind of loath vim script. I lean towards python, but am weary of excluding userbases

Comment: Whatever you do, plese share it with us :) I currently know just enough python to write a (buggy) hello world, but I'm currently leaning it; but Vim script..well..let's say I have a "strong dislike" for illegible mess vim script is. >_> Have you published your work so far?

Comment: Not unless I publish my brain. Don't wait up yet. Also, you got to teach me how to do buggy 'hello worlds' in python. That'd be an awesome party trick :)

Comment: This is indeed a genius thing for idea products. Since I use Vim mode in PyCharm I'm enjoying the best of both the worlds.

Comment: @drHannibalLecter Considering the fact that he is your 'ex' boss, hope that convo didn't become the reason why he became your ex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a quick go at this problem. It doesn't work as is. Feel Free to make edits and post on the vim wiki or as a plugin if you get it refined.

chances are you'd want to make a g:resharp_list for each language (eg. one for paranthesised languages, etc.)

All that is needed is a marker for the original cursor position :he markers and a timeout autocommand that resets the index.

```
"resharp emulator
"TODO this needs a marker
"also c-w is bad mapping as it has a lag with all the other-
"window mappings
"
let g:resharp_index = 0

let g:resharp_select =  ['iw', 'is', 'ip', 'ggVG']

func! ResharpSelect()
    if g:resharp_index >= len (g:resharp_select)
        let g:resharp_index = 0
    endif

    exe "norm \<esc>v" . g:resharp_select[g:resharp_index]
    let g:resharp_index = g:resharp_index + 1
endfun

nnoremap <c-w>  :call ResharpSelect()<cr>
vnoremap <c-w>  :call ResharpSelect()<cr>

"Something to reset on timeout. TODO this doesn't work
au CursorHold :let g:resharp_index = 0<cr>
```

Comment: Just tried it, it's a good start! Hopefully I'll learn vim script one day and extend it.

Comment: To make this more vim-y you should probably be implementing operator mappings.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes. Once in Visual mode you can use all the regular navigation methods as well as some extra ones.

Some of my favourites? First hit v while in normal mode to get to visual mode then hit:

1. *iw* - to select the inner word. Great for selecting a word while excluding surrounding braces or quotes
2. *w* - hit multiple times to keep selecting each subsequent word.
3. *b* - select wordwise backwords
4. *^* - select all from current position to beginning of text on line
5. *$* - select all from current position to end of line

I'm sure others here could add to this list as well. Oh and don't forget Visual Block mode C-v try it out in vim with the above commands it works in two dimensions :-)

Comment: I am relatively familiar with the visual mode, but the key difference is that you have to move your fingers around and actually think what you want to select next (or, in other words, _where_ to extend your selection). The goal is to merge all those sequentially to a single key combination. [I hope I am clear enough, I'm not a native english speaker]

Comment: Well, that's doable in Vim, you'd just have to write a vim function that cycled through various selection levels, and map a keystroke to that function.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about Vim (and you should be :-), you can start marking text with the `v` command, then you have all the standard cursor movement commands (and, as you know, there are a *lot* of them) which will extend the selection, as well as moving the cursor.

Then you just do whatever you want with the selected text.

See [here](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/visual.html#Visual) for the gory details.

Comment: The same comment as for Jeremy Wall :)

Answer (score 2):

One would need to write a function that would save the current selection, then try increasingly wide selections, until the new selection exceeds the saved one or selects all text. Some possible selections are:

- viW - select word
- vis - select sentence
- vip - select paragraph
- viB - select text within the innermost brackets
- v2iB - select text within the next most innermost brackets
- ggVG - select all text

Comment: This is exactly what I mean, only problem being I'm not familiar with the Vim scripting language. :(

Answer (score 1):

I think Jeremy Wall's heading in the right direction. And to get a little further in that direction, you might look at the "surround.vim" script from Tim Pope. A good description is available [on github](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/blob/master/doc/surround.txt). Or, if you'd rather, get it from [vim.org](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697). It'll probably help you do some of the things you'd like to do, though it doesn't seem to have a feature for say, simply selecting within a tag. Let me know if I'm wrong.

Ultimately, what you'd really like is a hierarchy of enclosing text-objects. You should read up on text-objects if you haven't. A nice overview is [here](http://blog.interlinked.org/tutorials/vim_tutorial.html). Note that you can grab multiple objects in one go using counts, or do this iteratively (try `vawasap}}}` from normal mode).

You can also get scripts which define other text-objects, like [this one](https://github.com/michaeljsmith/vim-indent-object) that uses indentation to define a text-object. It'll work for many languages if you're formatting according to common standards, and guaranteed for python.

One annoyance is that the cursor ends up at the end of the visual block, so, for example, you can't easily select everything between some ()'s, then get the function name that precedes them...

...BUT, I just found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196424/vim-object-select-with-syntax-aware-text-objects) that you can change this behavior with `o`. Cool!

I suspect you'll find yourself more efficient being able to skip over intermediate selections in the long run.

Anyway, I'll be curious to see if anyone else comes up with a more general solution as well!

Comment: Thanks for the links! Even though I asked this question a "long" time ago, Vim scripting still looks like magic to me :)

Answer (score 0):

In Rider [on a Mac with VS Mac bindings with IdeaVim], I bind:

- `Ctrl`+`=` to *Extend Selection*
- `Ctrl`+`-` to *Shrink Selection*

Doesn't clash with any other bindings of consequence and doesn't require a `v` for mode switching, and easier than `Cmd`+`Option`+`->` and  `Cmd`+`Option`+`<-`

---

Putting it here as I always hit this question with any `Rider Vim selection` searches. If I get enough harassment, I'll create a self-answered "How to use Extend Selection with Rider Vim mode".