# Vim object-select with syntax-aware text-objects

Tags: vim, select, text, syntax

I just learned about the truly awesome [object-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405415/can-you-grab-or-delete-between-parentheses-in-vi-vim/405419#405435) capabilities of vim.  With the cursor within some "text object", a set of simple verbs can select or operate on the whole object.  For example, with the cursor anywhere inside the quotes below (e.g. over the 'o'):

```
print "Hello, world"
           ^
```

The command `vi"` will select the whole phrase inside the quotes. The same capability works with a number of "[text objects](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#object-select)" that vim defines, including words, sentences, paragraphs, and characters enclosed by quotes, parentheses, and braces.

But now I want this notion of a "text object" to be aware of the language I'm writing.  For example, consider the following python:

```
re.sub("[^A-Z ]", " ", string)
```

I'd like to be able to place the cursor somewhere over that, and to select the whole thing.  The function call is a well-defined syntactic construct, but it isn't a "word", "sentence", "paragraph", or enclosed in quotes or braces.

Are there any plugins or vimrc hacks out there that define these sorts of language-dependent "text objects"?

Answer (score 4):

[This script](https://github.com/michaeljsmith/vim-indent-object) uses indentation to define a text-object. It'll work for many languages if you're formatting according to common standards, and guaranteed for python.

Comment: I just got a couple up-votes for this old response. But, if you're still in the market for something like this, python-mode includes actual python text objects for classes and methods (it's pretty comprehensive, but you can disable most of it): https://github.com/klen/python-mode

Answer (score 3):

Although it's is possible to construct maps that will [select an entire syntax region](http://vim.pastey.net/138094), that wouldn't work with your given scenario since there isn't a "function call" syntax region.

One option is to select the parenthetical expression and then extend that backwards to include the function call.

```
va)oB
```

- `va)` selects the parenthetical expression
- `o` toggles which end of the visual selection the cursor is at and which direction you're expanding.
- `B` moves the cursor backwards one WORD. That is, to the character just after the whitespace previous to the cursor.

Comment: Good answer, one gotcha though: this will only work if the cursor is inside the parenthesis but it won't work if the cursor is over the "re.sub" part.

Comment: Sure, but that's easily remedied with a leading `f(`.  Since there's no native way to do what's being asked, there are obviously going to be constraints on how the action can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2100) out there to create user defined text-objects.  Doesn't have a huge rating, but it might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

My take on the matter: https://github.com/ngn/vim-select-by-syntax

I didn't really want to make it a text object, but anyway, it solves the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

My [SameSyntaxMotion plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4338) provides mappings to jump to the borders and next [count] occurrences of text highlighted in the same way as under the cursor. The `ay` and `iy` text objects will select the
surrounding text that belongs to the same syntax group, or is highlighted the same way.

Comment: Is it on GitHub? I want Vundle install =)

Comment: It should be mirrored by http://vim-scripts.org, but I can't find it there. Kindly complain to the site's owners; seems their bot has missed it.